# Pygame window fails to open from inside python script

Tags: python, pygame-surface

I am trying to open a pygame surface on a Windows 10 PC. Following, are the steps needed to open a 800 by 600 window. The surface opens and displays correctly when invoked from a python shell as follows:

```
Python 3.7.3 (v3.7.3:ef4ec6ed12, Mar 25 2019, 22:22:05) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
>>> import pygame
pygame 1.9.6
Hello from the pygame community. https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html
>>> pygame.init()
(6, 0)
>>> size = (800, 600)
>>> pygame.display.set_mode(size)
<Surface(800x600x32 SW)>
>>> pygame.display.get_surface()
<Surface(800x600x32 SW)>
```

When I do the same operation within a python script, a get a trace back error:

> `pygame.error: No available video device**`

```py
pygame.init()
self.window = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))
self.screen = pygame.display.get_surface()
self.background = pygame.surface.Surface(self.screen.get_size()).convert()
self.background.fill((0, 0, 0))
pygame.mouse.set_visible(True)
```

> `File "C:\Users\timtru\Documents\PycharmProjects\core.py", line 25, in __init__
>       super(Pypboy, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
>     File "C:\Users\timtru\Documents\PycharmProjects\core.py", line 21, in __init__
>       self.window = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))
>       **pygame.error: No available video device**`

Why can I get the window in the shell, but get "No available video device" when the same steps are run in a script?

Answer (score 1):

At the start of the program, after you call pygame.init(), you need to call

```
pygame.display.init()
```

You need to initialise the display before you can use it. From the [docs](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.init),

> The display module cannot do anything until it is initialized.